# Database Schema in SqlDataSource

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, sqldatasource

I'm trying to let users search student by using First Name or Student ID in a textbox. The search result will be displayed in GridView control.

This is my `SelectCommand` in HTML

```
SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [student] WHERE (([FName] LIKE '%' + @FName + '%') AND ([SID] = @SID))
```

However, the line above is requesting users to enter both First Name & Student Id together to search. I've been trying to change it to :

```
SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [student] WHERE (([FName] LIKE '%' + @FName + '%') OR([SID] LIKE '%' + @SID + '%'))">
```

But it won't work. The error said

> System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.

PLS HELP. Why I can't put OR condition in SqlDataSource control?

Comment: Can you show us the code where you are assigning the parameters?, my guess is you are just getting one input from UI, but you are using two parameters in your query.

Comment: @MauricioAtanache I am using the sqldatasource to retrieve table `student` and display it into gridview. When configure the select statement in sqldatasource, I `select *` and clicked on `WHERE` button to add conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful here. I see to errors in the query.

First, let's say I search by `SID`, and leave the first name field blank. That will result in an expression like this:

```
WHERE FName LIKE '%%' OR SID LIKE '%1234%'
```

This is an `OR` condition, where the left side will match **anything**. It would *always* return *all* of the records. I also suggest making the SID search an exact match. If you've got an ID number for a student, you've got the *whole* ID number.

Second, `SID` is likely a numeric/integer field. ASP.Net needs to be able to convert your `SID` input into a number, even if that input is a blank string. This is where your error message is coming from.

My suggestion here is set your SQL CommandText for the datasource during the postback, for whatever event you handle to run this query. Build the string so it only includes the condition for the field(s) that were actually supplied by the user. *Still user paramterized queries to do this.*

Comment: Hi, I can search by First Name using this`SELECT * FROM [student] WHERE (([FName] LIKE '%' + @FName + '%')` . However, when I add one more condition in sqldatasource, it force me do like this `SELECT * FROM [student] WHERE (([FName] LIKE '%' + @FName + '%')  AND ([SID] = @SID))"` Meaning that I can't search using either SID or First Name

Comment: Been trying to change `AND` to `OR`, but it said `input string format is wrong`

Answer (score 0):

If you are just receiving one search parameter (Google Style), your SQL query should look like :

```
SELECT * FROM [student] WHERE (([FName] LIKE '%' + @searchPattern + '%') OR 
([SID] = @searchPattern )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to invert the SID with the name, another thing check the @SID parameter is a integer it must be a string, in the database [SID] is a varchar ?

If you programmatic modify the parameters pay attention to use defaults and not accidentally redeclare new parameters.

```
SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters["SID"].DefaultValue = "123";
```

Another thing if your SID is an integer you cannot use LIKE operator in sqlserver  you must cast it to a varchar

Comment: SID is an `Int` in database. Actually I configured select statement using SqlDataSource, When I add multiple conditions to `WHERE` clause, the select statement will become `WHERE condition1 AND condition2 AND condition3` instead of OR

Comment: If you programmatic modify the parameters pay attentio to use defaults and not accidentally redeclare new parameters.